# Взаимодействие Realm и GSON

Tags: android, realm, retrofit2, gson, realm-database

Интерфейс для `Retrofit`

```
public interface MapApi {

    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"})
    @POST("map/saveareas")
    Call<StandardResponse> saveAreas(@Body List<Area> areas);
}
```

Pojo класс Area

```
public class Area extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Expose
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @Expose
    private String parentId;
    @Expose
    private int color;
    @Expose
    private Date date = new Date();
    @Expose
    private boolean favourite = false;


    public Area(){}
//Другой конструктор и геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

Так вот, получаю список объектов из `Realm` и передаю этот список ретрофиту

```
List<Area> areas = mRealm
                    .where(Area.class)
                    .findAll();

if (areas != null) {
                try {
                    Call<StandardResponse> saveAreasResponseCall =
                            MyApplication.mMapApi.saveAreas(areas);

                    saveAreasResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<StandardResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<StandardResponse> call, Response<StandardResponse> response) {

                            Log.d(MyApplication.TAG, CLASS + ": " + response.code());

                            if (response.code() == 200) {
                                StandardResponse standardResponse = response.body();

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<StandardResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.e(MyApplication.TAG, CLASS + ": " + t.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(MyApplication.TAG, CLASS + ": " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

Приложение зависает с черным экраном, развисает спустя секунд 30 с ошибкой

```
E/tag: MapsFragment: stack size 8MB
```

Однако, если я сам создаю `List<Area> areas1`, в ручную наполняю его данными из того, что находится в `Realm` и передаю ретрофиту, то все работает. Например,

```
List<Area> areas1 = new ArrayList<>();
areas1.add(new Area("eb1737a1-9693-47d9-8390-5d02a249f5c4", "test", "test description", "", -10647809, new Date("Mon Feb 05 22:37:35 GMT+10:00 2018"), false));
areas1.add(new Area("7017c01a-cb6b-403f-956a-38eeedfca598", "tes", "", "eb1737a1-9693-47d9-8390-5d02a249f5c4", -5349889, new Date("Mon Feb 05 22:38:11 GMT+10:00 2018"), false));
```

Если я пытаюсь использовать `areas1.addAll(areas)`, чтобы опять же передать данные из списка, полученного из `Realm`, а потом передать новый список в `Retrofit`, то всё виснет снова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему не получалось передать список из `Realm` `Retrofit`-у?
Проблема скрывалась в использование `GSON` библиотеки.

Вольный перевод [Zhuinden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce) о том, почему GSON видит везде `null`

> Это потому, что GSON пытается прочитать поля объекта Realm посредством
>   рефлексии, но для получения значений вам нужно использовать методы
>   доступа, которые автоматически применяются ко всему доступу к полю в
>   коде через Realm-transformer, но рефлексия все еще видит null везде.

Конечно, можно создать кастомный `JsonSerializers` для каждого класса модели, но такой подход не рекомендуется.

Существует несколько решений проблемы, вот один из них, на мой взгляд самый практичный.

- Создаем дженерик интерфейс

  ```
  public interface CloneableRealmObject<T> {
  T cloneRealmObject();}
  ```
- Реализуем этот интерфейс в своем классе-модели.

  public class Area extends RealmObject implements CloneableRealmObject {

  ```
  @PrimaryKey
  @Expose
  private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  @Expose
  private String name;
  @Expose
  private String description;
  @Expose
  private String parentId;
  @Expose
  private int color;
  @Expose
  private Date date = new Date();
  @Expose
  private boolean favourite = false;


  public Area() {
  }

  @Override
  public Area cloneRealmObject() {
      Area cloneArea = new Area();
      cloneArea.id = this.id;
      cloneArea.name = this.name;
      cloneArea.description = this.description;
      cloneArea.parentId = this.parentId;
      cloneArea.color = this.color;
      cloneArea.date = this.date;
      cloneArea.favourite = this.favourite;
      return cloneArea;
  }
  ```

Теперь объект, полученный из `Realm` можно передать в `Retrofit`, предварительно вызвав у этого объекта метод `cloneableRealmObject()`.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044320/9007098)